# Install Elastic search 6+ in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3.2, elasticsearch

I am setting `Elastic Search 6+` in `Magento 2.3.2 CE`, but getting an issue

> Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException

I've not installed anything. I just enabled it from admin panel.
Any installation process or just enable from admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run Command

```
service elasticsearch restart
```

And wait for 1 minutes to Restart process then this error will resolve.

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Failed to restart elasticsearch.service: Unit elasticsearch.service not found.
I got this issue.. No need of any installation ?

Comment: This means your Unit elasticsearch.service not installed properly, try to properly installed ElasticSearch then, Properly configure ElasticSearch with Magento instance.

Comment: Refer this link properly. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html

Comment: Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException): No alive nodes found in your cluster .. Now i have installed elastic search and start service but it giving above issue.

Comment: have you properly configured your elastic search with magento ?